# How do I structure a package so that its modules are callable?

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and am learning how packages and modules work but have run into a snag. Initially I created a very simple package to be deployed as a Lambda function. I have a file in the root directory called `lambda.py` which contains a `handler` function, and I put most of my business logic in a separate file. I created a subdirectory - for this example let's say it's called `testme` - and more specifically put it in `__init__.py` underneath that subdirectory. Initially this worked great. Inside my `lambda.py` file I could use this `import` statement:

```
from testme import TestThing # TestThing is the name of the class
```

However, now that the code is growing, I've been splitting things into multiple files. As a result, my code no longer runs; I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here's a simplified version of what my code looks like now, to illustrate the problem. What am I missing? What can I do to make these modules "callable"?

**/lambda.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from testme import TestThing


def handler(event, context):
    abc = TestThing(event.get('value'))
    abc.show_value()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler({'value': 5}, None)
```

**/testme/__init__.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__project__ = "testme"
__version__ = "0.1.0"
__description__ = "Test MCVE"
__url__ = "https://stackoverflow.com"
__author__ = "soapergem"
__all__ = ["TestThing"]
```

**/testme/TestThing.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class TestThing:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def show_value(self):
        print 'The value is %s' % self.value
```

Like I said, the reason I'm doing all this is because the real world example has enough code that I want to split it into multiple files inside the subdirectory. And so I left an `__init__.py` file there to just to serve as an index essentially. But I am very unsure of what the best practices are for package structure, or how to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to import your class in your `__init__` file:

**testme/__init__.py**:

```
from .TestThing import TestThing
```

or import it using the full path:

**lambda.py**:

```
from testme.TestThing import TestThing
```

When you use a `__init__.py` file, you create a package, and this package (named after the root directory, e.g. testme, may include submodules. Those are accessible via the `package.module` syntax, but the contents of the submodules are only visible in the root package if you explicitly import them there.

Comment: Is either one more common? Or considered best practice?

Comment: Depends on your usecase. In large projects like numpy or scipy you find both: Common objects are visible in the root package, others only in subpackages, other submodules have to be imported explicitly by the user.